# Edit button does not have any functionality, no red circle with a minus appears on the left side of cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have looked at another question that was asking the exact same question as mine, but the answer told them to call the setEditing function (which I tried, and say later in the question). But I don't see how you could call this function only when the edit button is clicked. I suppose I could create my own BarButtonItem and run this method when my bar button item is clicked, but I figured this would be far easier since I need the basic functionality of the edit button.

I have a UIViewController that has a table on it named peersTable. When I click the edit button it switches to done, but nothing happens on the table. I have also added my own UITableViewRowActions and when I swipe to the left on the cells, my custom actions do show up.

Here is some of my code:

```
class PeerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ConnectionManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var peersTable: UITableView!
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    peersTable.delegate = self
    peersTable.dataSource = self

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    ...
}
```

I have also tried calling the peersTable.setEditing(true, animated: true) method myself, and in this case, the red minus does appear. I've never seen this issue before, so I don't understand why it's happening. Am I somehow setting the delegate wrong? Or possibly I'm doing something wrong since this is a regular View and not a TableView (even though I've done this before in a previous project).

Thanks in advance! If you need any more information let me know!

Comment: I also faced the same problem. I connected the table view with the class by creating a tableView property in the class like an outlet.  @IBOutlet weak var productTableView: UITableView! . The tableView in the storyboard and the tableView property must be connected. Though I don't know why this worked.

Comment: @RubaiyatJahanMumu I assume you mean by ctrl+dragging the tableView into PeerViewController class, which I have already previously done "@IBOutlet weak var peersTable: UITableView!" (and then set as the delegate and data source). Unless you meant something else...

Comment: Did you implement other delegate methods, especially `func tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:)`? If so, you'll have to return `.delete` here.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I don't think that this is necessary since in other projects I have got the editButton's functionality to work without implementing this method but I did try to implement it anyways and it still didn't work. But thank you for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a not a TableViewController it won't automatically set your tableView to editing mode when you press the edit button.

You need to override setEditing method so you can set the tableView to editing mode.

Add this to your ViewController class:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    peersTable.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```